# Raspberry Pi - Audio Fails After Adding RTC

Tags: clock, raspberry-pi, alsa

I have a Raspberry Pi that I'm trying to hook-up to walkie-talkies to announce the current time every half hour plus different status updates automatically.

I had a CRON job running mpg123 that was announcing the time over the walkies perfectly, but then when I installed the drivers for this RasClock module as specified here (https://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-rasclock-raspberry-pi-real-time-clock), all audio stopped working.

speaker-test says:

```
speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -1,Operation not permitted
```

and mpg123 says:

```
[module.c:142] error: Failed to open module jack: file not found 
[module.c:142] error: Failed to open module portaudio: file not found
[pulse.c:84] error: Failed to open pulse audio output: Connection refused
[nas.c:220] error: could not open default NAS server
[module.c:142] error: Failed to open module openal: file not found
[audio.c:180] error: Unable to find a working output module in this list: alsa,oss,jack,portaudio,pulse,nas,openal
[audio.c:532] error: Failed to open audio output module 
[mpg123.c:897] error: Failed to initialize output, goodbye.
```

Now, the machine tends to freeze up a lot, too. When I tried suggestions I found online, such as adding "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/mpg123" or "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib/mpg123" before the command, it made no difference.

What little hair I have left thanks you in advance for helping me through this.

Comment: Does your `/etc/modules` contain `snd_bcm2835`?

Comment: Also, the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`.  If it is empty, then the kernel upgrade you performed to get the *RTC* working has probably not included the *alsa snd_bcm2835* module.  As [ramblex](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297630/ramblex) notes, `modprobe` and `insmod` may no longer load the module due to kernel version differences.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message with **mpg123**.
Before this message, I installed all these packages: `mysql-server`, `build-essential`, `libmysqlclient-dev`, `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.
I also changed group:

```
# usermod -G anothergroup pi
```

One of these two manipulations have caused my problem.

---

The solution in my case ?
Go in the `/etc/group` file and modify the line beginning with "audio" from this...

```
audio:x:NN:
```

to that...

```
audio:x:NN:pi
```

N.B.: ***NN*** is the GID. ***pi*** is the Raspberry Pi's default username.

To achieve the same result, there is also this command :

```
# usermod -a -G audio pi
```

Log out from your session and log in again.

P.S.: Could somebody add the `mpg123` tag because I spent a lot of time without finding this topic, as I have exactly the same problem with **mpg123** ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue run this command should fix it `modprobe snd_bcm2835`